# Any reliable raster library in C?

Tags: library, image-processing, c, programming, png

I'd like a minimal library that'll allow me to read/write/manipulate raster image formats, like BMP and PNG.

Written in C99 or C11 or otherwise portable.

Any recommendations?

**Edit**
I need to:

- load bmp
- get bmp information like width, data, depth, etc
- access the BMP matrix data itself
- preferably dither down to 1 bit per pixel
- preferably save result to a file

**Edit**

Cross-platform for windows and linux (and android). The purpose is to read BMP (or PNG) data, maybe manipulate it (dither and horizontal padding - can be done later), and then push the data onto thermal printers using ESC/POS.

Comment: Which kind of manipulation you need?

Comment: @convert e.g. dither a BMP so the resulting matrix is 1 bit per pixel.  
I've been looking at [stb](https://github.com/nothings/single_file_libs), [clibs](https://github.com/nothings/single_file_libs) and [CCAN](https://ccodearchive.net/list.html) and getting kinda lost, some "reviews" would come in handy.

Comment: Gues you meaned Cimg from that stb link? The only library I know, which could do suc things, is OpenCV, but don´t think it can be called minimal.

Comment: Or did you meand by minimal, that it limited to raster stuf only?

Comment: @convert something along the lines of [qdbmp](https://github.com/cbraudo/qdbmp) i guess.

Comment: Is dither the only manipulation you want to perform?

Comment: If it´s only about dither, implementing it yourself could be posibly a solution? Here is a thread that could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65953579/how-to-implement-1-bit-dithering-using-java I know it´s about Java, but syntax is very similar for such example.

Comment: Are you looking for a paid solution or something available at no cost?

Comment: Edited the question.
@convert yes, i've implemented dithering.

Comment: @BenThompson no cost, please.

Comment: @vesperto So was that qdbmp a good solution, or you still serching for an other lib?

Comment: @convert if no one else comes up with a solution it'll do. That one or [libbmp](https://github.com/marc-q/libbmp).

Answer (score 0):

Two free software candidates would be:

- [Imlib2](https://docs.enlightenment.org/api/imlib2/html/) - image loading and rendering (however, no longer maintained)
- [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/), versatile image processor, with command-line interface and various APIs - the C API is [MagickWand](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php)

Comment: lmlib2 seems to be linux-only, magickwand seems to have way more features than i need.

Comment: @vesperto Since it´s open sorce, should be not really a problem to use it on diferent OS, like Windows. But as far I can see it is not minimal library.